# Extract Link URL After Specified Element with Python and Beautifulsoup4

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to extract a link from a page with python and the beautifulsoup library, but I'm stuck. The link is on the following page, on the sidebar area, directly underneath the h4 subtitle "Original Source:

http://www.eurekalert.org/pub_releases/2016-06/uonc-euc062016.php

I've managed to isolate the link (mostly), but I'm unsure of how to further advance my targeting to actually extract the link. Here's my code so far:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "http://www.eurekalert.org/pub_releases/2016-06/uonc-euc062016.php"
data = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(data.text, 'lxml')

source_url = soup.find('section', class_='widget hidden-print').find('div', class_='widget-content').findAll('a')[-1]

print(source_url)
```

I am currently getting the full html of the last element in which I've isolated, where I'm trying to simply get the link. Of note, this is the only link on the page I'm trying to get.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You almost got it!!

---

**SOLUTION 1:**

You just have to run the `.text` method on the `soup` you've assigned to `source_url`.

So instead of:

```
print(source_url)
```

You should use:

```
print(source_url.text)
```

---

**Output:**

> http://news.unchealthcare.org/news/2016/june/e-cigarette-use-can-alter-hundreds-of-genes-involved-in-airway-immune-defense

---

**SOLUTION 2:**

You should call `source_url.get('href')` to get only the specific `href` tag related to your `soup.findall` element.

```
print source_url.get('href')
```

**Output:**

> http://news.unchealthcare.org/news/2016/june/e-cigarette-use-can-alter-hundreds-of-genes-involved-in-airway-immune-defense

Comment: Perfect, thanks! Also, thanks for the alt. approach suggestion; I'm new to python and am still soaking in best-practices.  Also, thanks for the quick reply, I can't even accept the answer yet!

Comment: Don't worry mate. You've provided a good question and showed us some of your efforts. And as I said, you almost got it ;-)

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for the link which is the `href` html attribute. source_url is a `bs4.element.Tag` which has the `get` method like:

```
source_url.get('href')
```